# Passing System.Drawing.Point to MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass two System.Drawing.Point structs to my controller . While it is possible to create plain objects to simply get the positions, I was curios if it is possible to use a built-in struct to achieve the same task.

I couldn't hit any breakpoints with these signatures:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething(Point pt1, Point pt2)
```

and

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething(Point pt)
```

I *did* hit a breakpoint to this signature,

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething(Point[] pts)
```

with this request:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:37260/TestController/DoSomething',
            dataType: 'application/json',
            success: function (myData) { },
            data: [{X: 5, Y: 6}, {X: 7, Y: 9}],
            async: false
        });
```

but points were null. I also tried bunch of other things.
I'm using jQuery and JSON but it is not a requirement. Also, it can be either POST or a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

use `DoSomething(int x, int y)` instead of `DoSomething(Point pt)`
here Point is .net system object. so use int parameter and in that block define new Point(x, y) object.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion but I'm trying to find out if it is possible (or impossible) to pass a built-in .NET struct, System.Drawing.Point to MVC controller because I could not find any example that uses it.

Comment: yes possible but you do not call action from jQuery because jQuery do not understand .net system object. If you direct call action with out using jQuery then it is possible.

Comment: otherwise create your own class.

Comment: `Public class iPoint
{
 public int x {get; set;}
 public int y {get; set;}
}

public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething(iPoint pt)
{
 Point obj = new Point(pt.x, pt.y);
 // use obj 
}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion again. That's why I started my question with "While it is possible to create plain objects to simply get the positions".